# CSS background image stretch with background-image property

Tags: html, css

I need to stretch the background image on the screen and fit when resizing it on this website DELETED, does anybody know?

```
<body>
  <div id="background"></div>
  ...
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS file:

```
html, body { }
body { height:100%; width: 100%; }
#background{ position: fixed; min-height: 1024px; height:100%; min-width: 100%; width: auto; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index:1 }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the `background-image` on the `body`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find everything you need here:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @TomášBěloch - [Here is another good source.](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)